# Switch primary card

Tags: nvidia, graphics

When I installed Ubuntu 22.10 the primary card was the intel and then my Nvidia like this, but now the first card display in the About section is the Nvidia card:

[image]

And I can't launch the game Doom Eternal anymore.

How to reverse the order of these 2 cards and get Mesa In HD Graphics 630 first?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Two things might be causing problems:

1)Check your PrefersNonDefaultGPU setting in /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop.   This interacts with the power mode: Performance makes the high power GPU the default, Balanced does not -- or at least it used to. This setting depends upon how the default is set, I'd wish they'd make it something like Use the dedicated GPU x.
2) Laptops use a hybrid GPU setup, the integrated one (Intel) runs the display and the dedicated one does the real work.  Sometimes this assignment gets switched -- again seems like some "default" mixup.  See the situation in a terminal with the command:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x250 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

This is the reversed situation -- affects only some things like the CUDA samples (they die instantly).  Individually switch what a program uses with:

__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia

Permanent change may be made, but the assignment seems to change randomly, so better to figure out which programs use the "default" when they really want the "dedicated" and run appropriately.

Comment: That's pretty strange, yesterday I could run Doom Eternal once after multiple crash and today impossible to run it, it crash on startup after a few seconds. I had 
`PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true` on the steam.desktop file changed to to `false` but the game crash as well. I don't understand why being able to launch this game is so uncertain without changing any settings! My next computer won't be with a Nvidia card for sure.